# C++ Detect collision between two points and bouncing off the normal if there is a collision

Tags: c++, vector, collision-detection, normals

I have a ground set up of various points, some of which are flat and others are at an angle, I'm trying to check if there is a collision between the angled points (non-axis aligned).

I have a vector array consisting of two floats at each point - This is each of the points of the ground.

Here's an image representation of what the ground looks like.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZcnI.png

At the moment I want to check collisions between points 1 and 2 and then go onto the others.

I shall use points 1 and 2 as an example.

```
g1x = 150; g2x = 980;
g2x = 500; g2y = 780;
```

The dxdy of this is dx = 350 and dy = -200

The normal x of this is dy and the normal y is -dx

```
nx = -200;
ny = -350;
```

normalized it is the length between points 1 and 2 which is 403.11

nx/normalized = -0.496
ny/normalized = -0.868

```
//get position of object - Don't know if its supposed to be velocity or not
float vix = object->getPosition().x;
float viy = object->getPosition().y;

//calculate dot product - unsure if vix/viy are supposed to be minused
float dot = ((-vix * nrmx) + (-viy * nrmy)) * nrmx; //= -131.692
```

Is this information correct to calculate the normal and dot product between the two points.

How can I check if there is a collision with this line and then reflect according to the normal.

Thanks :) any and all changes are welcome.

Comment: My suggestion is you pick up a book on linear algebra (or even game mathematics might do). If you have one of these problems then you will probably have more like it. As a start, look into things like vector projection or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a particle at position **x** travelling at velocity **v** and a boundary defined by the line between **a** and **b**.

We can find how far along the boundary (as a fraction) the particle collides by projecting **c**-**a** onto **b**-**a** and dividing by the length ||**b**-**a**||. That is,

*u* = ((**c**-**a**)**.**((**b**-**a**)/||**b**-**a**||))/||**b**-**a**|| == (**c**-**a**)**.**(**b**-**a**) / ||**b**-**a**||<sup>2</sup>.

If *u* > 1 then the particle travels past the boundary on the **b** side, if *u* < 0 then the particle travels past the boundary on the **a** side. The point of collision would be

**c** = **a** + *u* **b**.

The time to collision could be found by solving

**x** + *t* **v** = **a** + *s* (**b**-**a**)

for *t*. The reflection matrix can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Reflection). But it will need to be rotated by 90 *deg* (or pi/2) so that you're reflecting orthogonal to the line, not across it.

In terms of multiple boundaries, calculate the time to collision for each of them, sort by that time (discarding negative times) and check for collisions through the list. Once you've found the one that you will collide with then you can move your particle to the point of collision, reflect it's velocity, change the *delta* *t* and redo the whole thing again (ignoring the one you just collided with) as you may collide with more than one boundary in a corner case (get it? It's a maths pun).

Linear algebra can be fun, and you can do so much more with it, getting to grips with linear algebra allows you to do some powerful things. Good luck!